# PRODUCT_NOT_ENABLED issue in Plaid API call

Tags: php, laravel, assets, plaid

We try to run the "link/token/create" API call, but it throws the PRODUCT_NOT_ENABLED error

We use the sandbox account testing details.

Below are our error response details

```
{\n
  "display_message": null,\n
  "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#asset-report-errors-and-warnings",\n
  "error_code": "PRODUCT_NOT_ENABLED",\n
  "error_message": "the 'assets' product is not enabled for the following access tokens: access-sandbox-f075e55a-2cc1-4383-b8d3-d2c45159087b. please ensure that 'assets' is included in the 'product' array when initializing Link and create the Item(s) again.",\n
  "error_type": "ASSET_REPORT_ERROR",\n
  "request_id": "Yjl31xcFu62n7Jp",\n
  "suggested_action": null\n
}
```

Can you please provide feedback on this issue?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://plaid.com/docs/errors/item/#product_not_enabled), `You requested a product that was not enabled for the current access token. Ensure it is included when when calling /link/token/create and create the Item again.` You don't provide any code, so couldn't tell you anything beyond that.

Comment: Hi Aynbar,  We already checked the Plaid API documentation. If you know the product enables process please share me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get enabled for a product you're not already enabled for, you can request access at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/products or by contacting your Plaid Account Manager.